# Check whether the service is installed or not in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, service, systemctl

I am trying to get the service whether it is installed or not. The script is working fine with systemctl but fails where systemctl is not installed. As an alternative to that I am using service command to check but by doing so I am unable to run the grep command to grep specific service. This script needs to run on multiple linux machine (some with systemctl and some without it). Any help would be appreciated

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

serviceName=ngnix.service

if (systemctl --all --type service || service --status-all) && grep -q "$serviceName";then
    echo "$serviceName exists."
else
    echo "$serviceName does NOT exist."
fi
```

output without systemctl:

```
./test.sh: line 5: systemctl: command not found
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  mariadb
 [ - ]  nginx
 [ - ]  nginx-debug
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  redis-server
 [ - ]  rsync
```

output with systemctl:

```
ngnix.service does NOT exist.
```

Comment: Try `serviceName=ngnix`

Answer (score 1):

Place both commands in a command-group and redirect the whole command-group to `grep`:

```sh
if { systemctl --all --type service || service --status-all; } 2>/dev/null |
  grep -q "$serviceName"; then
  echo "$serviceName exists."
else
  echo "$serviceName does NOT exist."
fi
```

Comment: how will I provide the service name as in systemctl it is `service.nginx` but for service command its only `nginx`?

Comment: In service command it is not able to detect the service whether it is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

systemctl is a control utility for managing systemd units. You can try checking nginx presence inside /usr/lib/systemd/ in case of systemd based init system. Don't forget the philosophy "Everything is a file."
See [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for more explanation.
For ancient distros with `init` init system check directory /etc/init.d/ see [man service](https://linux.die.net/man/8/service)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check if the system has sysV or initd inside you can search just for the binary. If the binary exists, you can assume that the package and the services are installed. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

is_nginx_exists=$(which nginx)

if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        echo "YES"
else
        echo "NO"
fi
```

Explanation:

> which nginx - will try to find the nginx binary from a system wide
> binaries list;
>
> $? - this command determinate if previous command    executed
> successfully. In our case 0 means that the binary was found;

It's fast, clean and most important works in regular VM, docker container, etc.